# Ubuntu Core 18 - How install snapcraft?

Tags: software-installation, snap, ubuntu-core

I'm looking for the right method to install snapcraft on Ubuntu Core 18.
I've tried it with the command:

```
sudo snap install snapcraft
```

but I get the error:

> error: snap "snapcraft" requires classic confinement which is only available on classic systems

Without snapcraft I can't dig in the store looking for my private snaps!

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm still a bit of an Ubuntu-Core noob, so please forgive any errant assumptions expressed here, but I was able to get the [snapcraft tutorial](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-your-first-snap/14006/1) to work on an Ubuntu Core 18 system using the "classic" snap on an RBP 3B+ running [ubuntu-core-18-armhf+raspi3.img.xz](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi-2-3-core).

After the maiden Core boot on the pi and completing the network configuration: I logged in with my Ubuntu SSO and gave the fresh install a few minutes to update with the Ubuntu mother ship.  After it rebooted, I logged back in and installed the classic snap from the edge channel:

```
sudo snap install --channel=edge classic --devmode
```

Then I ran the classic snap.

```
lh@localhost:~$ sudo classic
(classic)lh@localhost:~$
```

The first time I ran it a ton of stuff happened changing my env substantially.  Afterwards I received a courtesy message saying:

> This version of classic was build for Ubuntu Core 16. You appear to be
>   using a different version of Ubuntu Core. You can install different
>   versions of the classic environment, e.g. for Ubuntu Core 18:

I then exited classic and refreshed the snap from Core using the 18/edge channel.  It's worth noting that installing the classic snap fresh from the 18/edge channel did not work for me.  The reasons for that aren't so germane to this topic though.

```
(classic)lh@localhost:~$ exit
lh@localhost:~$ sudo snap refresh --channel=18/edge --devmode classic
```

Once refreshed I logged back into classic and was happy to find I could:

```
lh@localhost:~$ sudo classic
(classic)lh@localhost:~$ sudo apt update
(classic)lh@localhost:~$ sudo apt install snapcraft
```

After all the "apt-ing output", I could follow the snapcraft tutorial pretty much line for line.  The only thing I did differently was after the snap built, I exited classic and installed the hello snap in my Core environment.  It installed fine, but didn't run as my PATH wasn't set correctly.  I found the binary in /snap/hello/current/bin, it ran fine using the [FQPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name).  :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install the snap of snapcraft on Ubuntu Core because it's classic and classic (unconfined) snaps do not work on Core.

You could however `snap login` to login to the store as your account and then `snap info mysnap` to view details about your private snaps.

Comment: But with **snapcraft** command i can see private snap and get info about them without know the name, only because i'm logged in the right account! Can use **snap** command to gather the same info ??